# Economic Theories for the creation of a new or separate Industry?

Tags: reference-request

Hey i'm doing a paper on the creation of an industry that has spawned from the another industry. I was wondering if there was particularly any interesting economic theory i should look at.

Some of my ideas For example because of the inherent social values of society demand is formed for newer services not traditionally offered by the industry creating a niche market segment. To which i guess i can talk about utility maximisation. And that's about how much i have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at monopolistic competition. It basically details how many industries can find their own niche in a differentiated product market. Some prominent papers in the subject:

- [Dixit and Stigliz: Monopolistic Competition and Optimum Product Diversity](https://assets.aeaweb.org/assets/production/journals/aer/top20/67.3.297-308.pdf)
- [Krugman: Increasing returns, monopolistic competition, and international trade](https://www.princeton.edu/pr/pictures/g-k/krugman/krugman-increasing_returns_1978.pdf)
- [Salop: Monopolistic Competition with Outside Goods](http://www.tcd.ie/Economics/staff/ppwalsh/papers/Salop.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The literature on innovation deals with activities such as research and development that give rise to new products. A good reference is "[Innovation and Incentives](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/innovation-and-incentives)" by Scotchmer.